# Avoid fatal error with `new $className()`?

Tags: php, oop

`new $className()` triggers a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Class 'foo' not found in /bar/baz.class.php on line 123

Is it possible to avoid that fatal error and continue? For example,
is it possible to check if the class named `$className` is available prior to requesting an instance?

Comment: You could use [class_exists()](http://us2.php.net/class_exists) prior to instantiating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`class_exists`](http://php.net/class_exists) method:

```
if (class_exists($className)) {
 $obj = new $className();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`class_exists()`](https://www.php.net/class_exists)

```
if (class_exists($classname)) {
    $myclass = new $classname();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need this:

```
class_exists($className)
```